# How do I make a read-only file system writable for pendrive

Tags: usb, filesystem, usb-drive, format, read-only

When I am trying to format my pendrive, I'm getting the following error.

```
root@obbu-G41M-Combo:/home/obbu# mkfs.vfat -n 'Ubuntu' -I /dev/sdb1
mkfs.vfat 3.0.14 (23 Jan 2023)
mkfs.vfat: unable to open /dev/sdb1: Read-only file system
```

Comment: Please execute the following command and update your question with the response:

    cat /etc/fstab

Comment: The content of `/proc/mounts` would be helpful too.

Answer (score -3):

Try copying all your files on the drive somewhere else. Then:

- Install `gparted`:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install gparted
  ```
- Run gparted and select the drive (`/dev/sdb ?`)
- Click on the `Device` from menu and select `Create partition`
- Right click on the `Unallocated space` and click `Create partition`.
- Create a new `msdos` partition and click the <kbd>apply</kbd> button.

If the problem lies with the drive itself this might help. If the problem lies with the way Ubuntu is handling pen drives then we would need logs as @gertvdijk pointed out.